# Libgdx dont remove actors from Stage

Tags: java, libgdx

i have problem with libgdx. I'm working on program, that have input for boxes and then you can chose algorhytm to sort them into truck.

[image]

I have problem with removig boxes. After i use this code, which should remove all actors, which are Textures(boxes).

```
for(Actor actor : stage.getActors()){
        if(actor.getClass() == Textures.class){
            actor.remove();
        }
    }
```

Sorting algorithm work good and all boxes are in the truck, but it doesn't remove some of the old boxes.
[image]

Then i try to use delete them by `actor.getName()`. Same result. There is also code whitch create actors:

```
for(Actor actor : stage.getActors()){
        if(actor.getName()!=null){
            if(actor.getName().equals("shape")){
                actor.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    //create actors
    for (ShapeMeasurments sh:shapes) {
        Textures textures = new Textures((sh.getX()*1.45f+30),sh.getY()*1.45f,sh.getWidth()*1.45f,
                sh.getHeight()*1.45f,sh.getMaterial());
        textures.setName("shape");
        stage.addActor(textures);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a problem. `actor.remove()` is problem in foreach loop. Removing actors in foreach loop can cause problems. So then i use `actor.addAction(Actions.removeActor());` and it works. That was said in [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121467/remove-actors-from-stage/32038903)

And don't use `if(actor.getClass() == Textures.class)` comparing classes is not trivial operation, you should use `actor.setName()` and `actor.getName()`.